# Getting JSON info in python

Tags: python, json

Sample of the database:

```
"metros" : [
        {
            "code" : "SCL" ,
            "name" : "Santiago" ,
            "country" : "CL" ,
            "continent" : "South America" ,
            "timezone" : -4 ,
            "coordinates" : {"S" : 33, "W" : 71} ,
            "population" : 6000000 ,
            "region" : 1
        } , {
            "code" : "LIM" ,
            "name" : "Lima" ,
            "country" : "PE" ,
            "continent" : "South America" ,
            "timezone" : -5 ,
            "coordinates" : {"S" : 12, "W" : 77} ,
            "population" : 9050000 ,
            "region" : 1
        }
```

I'm trying to print all city names. My code is:

```
Jdata = json.loads(self.data)
for i in Jdata["metros"]:
    print Jdata["name"]
```

But when I run this I'm getting "KeyError: 'name'"

What's the correct syntax to get the name of the cities?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
for city in Jdata['metros']:
    print city['name']
```

When you use `Jdata['name']`, it tries to look for the key in metros, which obviously does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
{"metros":[{"code":"SCL","name":"Santiago","Region":"1"},{"code":"LIM","name":"Lima","Region":"1"}],
}
```

Then you can use your code:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
json_data=open('json_data')

data = json.load(json_data)
pprint(data)
json_data.close()
With data, you can now also find values in like so:

data["metros"][1]["name"]
```